# Laravel - database select query with multiple conditions

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to create simple search query in db with multiple conditions.

I would like to search in db posts checking **tags** attached to posts and check searching word in posts **title**.

So far I made query that checks multiple tags for posts, but I'm struggling now how to check multiple words in post title.

```
$search = $request['search'];
$searchArr = explode(' ',$request['search']);
$searchTitle = [];

foreach ($searchArr as $search){
    $searchTitle[] = ['title','like', "%$search%"];
}

echo Post::with(['allTags'])->whereHas('allTags', function($query) use ($searchArr) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($searchArr); $i++) {
        if($i==0) {
            $query->Where('name', $searchArr[$i]);
        }else{
            $query->orWhere('name', $searchArr[$i]);
        }

    }
})->where(['published'=>1])->orWhere([['title','like', "%$search%"],['published','=','1']])->get();
```

As you see I use the "for" loop to check multiple tags but I can't find a way how to do it in this part of code `->orWhere([['title','like', "%$search%"],['published','=','1']])->get();`

Could someone tell me how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Small tip for the `->whereHas('allTags'` closure: You don't need to use `$query->where(` for the first constraint, you can use `$query->orWhere(` for all constraints.

Comment: I followed your tip, then query pull out from DB all records from table "post". When I use "Where" for first constraint then everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you need to use `whereRaw` method.

Be careful this can lead to SQL Injection

```
foreach ($searchArr as $search) {
    $searchTitle[] = ['title','like', "%$search%"];
}
```

You should probably build SQL and then bind using underlying PDO object with whereRaw method:

```
$searchQuery = implode(',', array_map(function($item) { return 'title like \"?\"'; }, $searchArray));
```

And then in your query string:

```
...->whereHas('allTags', function($query) use ($searchQuery, $searchArray) {
    $query->whereRaw($searchQuery, $searchArray, 'or');
})
```

Even easier if you actually are checking against title on Post

```
...->whereRaw($searchQuery, $searchArray, 'or')
```

Also make sure to check comments.

Comment: Thank you for answer. If I use this method am I prof from SQL Injections? foreach ($searchWords as $i){
            $searchQuery[] =  "title like ?";
        } "orWhereRaw($searchQuery,$searchWordsArray)->get()" Is it that underlay PDO statements?

Answer (score -1):

as per my understanding you want to break the words in your search string if it contains multiple words as in the following example:

```
<?php
$search_term = 'test1 test2 test3';
$keywords = explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $search_term));
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
 $wherelike[] = "title LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
}
$where = implode(" and ", $wherelike);

$query = "select * from table where $where";

echo $query;
```

and use Laravel `whereRaw()` method to execute this as a raw query

Comment: Thank you for answer. Why do you use "preg_replace"?